# MS Access 2007 - Query inside query inside query inside query

Tags: ms-access

I have a big Access database I am working on, designed by someone else.  I am trying to improve it.  The way it was set up, first you run Query 1 which makes Table A.  Then, run Query 2, which used Table A among others, and made Table B.  Then run Query 3, which uses Table B and makes Table C.  Then run Query 4, which uses Table C and makes Table D.  The final output we use is Table D.

My improvement here was to change Query 1, Query 2, and Query 3 to Select queries, instead of make table queries, and changing the SQL simply by find and replace (for example, in Query 2, replace all the instances of Table A with Query 1 instead).  Query 4 is still a make table query and it makes Table D which I export to Excel later.

My question: Can I just run Query 4?  That is, will that automatically run Query 3, which will automatically run Query 2, which will automatically run Query 1?  Or, do I need to run Query 1 first, then run Query 2, then run Query 3, then run Query 4?

Perhaps beyond that, can I make Query 4 a Select query also?  Then, I wouldn't even run Query 4.  Instead, I would just export Query 4 itself to Excel and I'm wondering if that would automatically run Query 4, which would run Query 3, and so on.

Just to be clear: I'm not looking for any SQL tips here.  I want to keep it just using Access (which is a front-end for SQL, I know) for now.

Note: I realize that one answer here is, "Why don't you try it?"  I have and it seems to work as I think it should.  The problem is, I have already run all the queries many times before, so I don't know if that makes everything work for now but maybe it won't work the same way later if I haven't already run the previous queries.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not just give the end user a button on a form that executes the queries in the proper order in VBA then shows the final result as a table or report?  Especially in your case where the ordering of the queries is crucial to the final output.

Comment: @WilliamStearns I am the end user.  Your answer is definitely a good idea.  But, this is as much about me learning how Access works as it is getting this one project to work.

Comment: Ok, well you can go change your SQL on the Query 4 to include the other queries' SQL as table aliases in your joins.  With this, you wouldn't need to have the other queries as real tables.

Comment: If query 4 refers to various other select queries, opening query 4 will "run" the other select queries. If this is about learning, I think one of the best ways to learn is to try it. If you are having oroblems with SQL, you need to post the SQL.

Comment: @Remou This is why I included in my question specifically that I had already tried it and explaining why I am asking any way :)  I am also changing some data in one of the beginning tables and then only running Query 4 and looking to see if the data is updated.  It appears to me that it is.  You also say that it should work this way.  This combination makes me comfortable that this way should work.

Comment: @Remou What about exporting?  As I asked at the bottom of my question, if I chang Query 4 to a Select query and then export Query 4, will that automatically run Query 4 and all previous queries?

Comment: The reason I am a little cagey in my comment is that I am not sure what your queries are doing, but any fairly straight-up query and most curly ones should export just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olivier already mentioned, yes selecting from SELECT queries works as you expect. You can actually test this by creating this function in a module

```
Function LogQueryCall(ByVal query As String)

    Debug.Print query & " " & Now

End Function
```

an then calling it from your queries e.g.

Query1

```
   SELECT *, LogQueryCall("Query1") FROM Table1 ;
```

Query2

```
  SELECT *, LogQueryCall("Query2") 
  FROM Query1 
     INNER JOIN Table2 
     ON Query1.Field = table2.Field
```

Query3

```
  SELECT *, LogQueryCall("Query3") FROM Query2
```

Then you'll see the results in the Immediate Window

```
Query1 01/03/2012 5:54:46 PM
Query2 01/03/2012 5:54:46 PM
Query3 01/03/2012 5:54:46 PM
```

Note the function will only get called once per query not once per row

Another option is to create 1 big query. This would use the contents of each query in the from clause like so.

```
SELECT *
FROM       
     (Select * FROM Table1) A
     INNER JOIN Table2 
     ON a.Field = table2.Field
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, "Yes, you can nest SELECT queries and just export to Excel by just exporting the outer-most query result".

Queries can be used exactly like tables in many situations. The nested queries will execute their own SELECT statement and pass their result to the surrounding query as if it was a table.

If query2 calls query1 and
query3 calls query2 and
qyery4 calls query3
... then the queries will automatically be executed in the order shown below by passing their result to the next query when you execute query4:

table -> query1 -> query2 -> query3 -> query4

I assume that your queries look something like this:

```
query1: SELECT * FROM table;
query2: SELECT * FROM query1;
query3: SELECT * FROM query2;
query4: SELECT * FROM query3;
```